# Is there a chat field?

Tags: 7

i searched for long time for a solution to make a chat room per node, i want to display a chat room as a field in my content type.

Is there a module for that?
Is there is not there is a php code or java script that can added in a field to display it?
thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://drupal.org/project/shoutbox, it should work in combination with http://drupal.org/project/og so you can limit it to one node.

Comment: it's not what i need